# Getting formcollection data in the controller from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

pretty new with MVC to maybe I am doing something wrong here .So I have a view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div>
        <label>Start Date : </label>
        <input readonly="true" type="text" id="startDate" style="Width:150px" />
        <br />
        <label>End Date : </label>
        <input type="text" id="endDate" readonly="true" style="Width:150px" />
        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
        <br />
    </div>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#startDate').datepicker();
        jQuery('#endDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

and in the action result in my Home controller I have this

```
 public ActionResult Reports()
        {

            return this.View();
        }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reports(FormCollection form)
    {

        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(form["startDate"].ToString());
        DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(form["endDate"].ToString());
        //Something with dates

    }
```

The issue is that FormsCollection is just empty .So no data is coming through from view to controller.I have seen online examples working like this.Is there some configuration I am missing or something else that I gotta do to get the FormsCollection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have readonly on your HTML input fields. These fields are not posted to the server, it is by design. Try removing the readonly attribute and it should work

EDIT: It seems I was wrong on what the issue was. Readonly fields are actually passed to the server, disabled fields aren't. In your case it was the missing name attribute that was the issue. My answer would have been correct if you had the input fields disabled.

Comment: But I want those fields to be read only so the user can select dates from only the date picker ..any workaround for this.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you need to have a name attribute, because in MVC properties are mapped by name not by Id